# How to get the partition column names for a table?

Tags: sql, hiveql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table that is partitioned on one or more columns. I can do ...

```
SHOW PARTITIONS table_db.table_1
```

which gives a list of all partitions like this,

```
year=2007
year=2015
year=1999
year=1993
```

but I am only interested in finding which columns the table is partitioned on, in this case, `year`. And I would like to be able to do this of multiple tables at once, giving me a list of their names and partitioned columns somewhat like this.

```
table_name       partition_col
table_1          year
table_2          year, month
```

I tried the solutions here...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html#querying-glue-catalog-listing-partitions

```
SELECT * FROM table_db."table_1$partitions"
```

does give me results with one column for each partition...

```
#     year
1     2007
2     2015
3     1999
4     1993
```

...but I couldn't extract the column names from this query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```sql
SELECT table_name,
    array_join(array_agg(column_name), ', ') as partition_col
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE extra_info = 'partition key'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Better use aws client than athena query, it's way faster and less resource consumming

Answer (score 0):

Get metadatas with AWS client provided in your language, like [boto3 athena](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_table_metadata) for python

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client()

table = client.get_table_metadata(
    CatalogName=catalog,
    DatabaseName=database,
    TableName=name
)["TableMetadata"]

partition_keys = table["PartitionKeys"]
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems solution is for mysql not SQL Server.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70999792/2227743) rather than a new answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31578075)